# Text not aligning properly with bootstrap's navbar-text pull-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following code in the html file:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <a href="index.html" class="brand">Hello Bootstrap</a>
                  <p class="navbar-text pull-right">This is first notice.</p><br/>
                  <p class="navbar-text pull-right">This is second notice. </p>
              </div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

I am getting the output like this:

[image]

Notice that "This is second notice" is not aligned properly with respect to the line above it. I am trying to get the two notices aligned properly with each other.

I also tried removing `<br/>` from code above but with that I get the following output: 
[image]

Could someone please point me what I am doing wrong?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N6vGZ/23/

Comment: Where is your CSS to style that? HTML is probably NOT your problem. And do you have an image showing how you want it to be? You want the second notice aligned right below the first, right?

Comment: it should be getting formatting styles from bootstrap.min.css no? I have not specified any rules for this class in my css.

Comment: Maybe you could put your code up on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: No, I want it like it is in the first image. Just wanted the second notice to be indented so that they are one below the other.

Comment: Try adding `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after This is first notice line's tag.

Comment: @anuragbh, that's not a good practice hehe... but it could work... I wanted to see what he has to style that, a chunk of css would be fine...

Comment: @anuragbh it does work with what you suggested but now the problem is that I don't want the empty line between notice 1 and notice 2. :-(

Comment: Removing the br tag or the p tag might fix that. You could use span instead of p and use a br too.

Comment: @anuragbh still the same http://jsfiddle.net/N6vGZ/26/

Comment: The empty line is because of the 40px line-height property for .navbar .navbar-text. Adjust it to a smaller size like 20px and it should remove the space.

Comment: You mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/N6vGZ/27/#run

Comment: @test123 i don't understand, you want both `p` tags to be one in top of the other? inline?

Comment: @AndresIlich sorry for not being clear. What I am trying to achieve is as mentioned in the image 1 in original post but having the second notice indented properly. So basically end result would be two notices in different lines (with no extra white line between the two, as in image 1) and 2nd notice indented properly so that it falls exactly below notice 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason both paragraphs are not aligning properly in the navbar is because the default `line-height` of `40px` set forth by the bootstraps doesn't allow them both to stack correctly. You can fix that by setting a lower `line-height`, something like `20px` should do the trick.

Note: i included both paragraphs inside a container that i can easily float and target with my own class, as not to bother the other elements around it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a href="index.html" class="brand">Hello Bootstrap</a>
            <div class="notices pull-right">
                <p class="navbar-text">This is first notice.</p>
                <p class="navbar-text">This is second notice.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.notices p {
    line-height:20px !important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N6vGZ/29/

Comment: @kaiser i dont understand your comment, care to explain?

Comment: @kaiser: Yes, it does. According to the spec, it can have a "length" type value: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height

See the "length" definition here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length

Comment: @jricher wow. I was 110% sure about this for since like ever.

Comment: @kaiser is this what it was about? i merely modified a class which is already included in the bootstrap with the `line-height` value of `40px`, a class which reads` .navbar-text { color: #777777; line-height: 40px; margin-bottom: 0;}`. confused as to why the downvote :/

Answer (score 3):

You didn't include the css but I assume that you have "float: right" on your "pull-right" class.

I think the easiest way to solve it is to wrap the two p's in their own div and float that dive right:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <a href="index.html" class="brand">Hello Bootstrap</a>
              <div class="pull-right">
                   <p class="navbar-text">This is first notice.</p>
                   <p class="navbar-text">This is second notice. </p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Don't forget to set a width on the "pull-right" class in your css if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply J. Greene. It works with what you suggested but it is putting an empty line between Notice 1 and Notice 2. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Yes, you have those wrapped in p tags. I like to think of a br tag as a single space and a p tag as a double space.

You can wrap the two lines in "span" (instead of "p") with the class navbar-text and put a single br between, or you can adjust the spacing between the paragraphs with styles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply J. Greene. Adjusting the spacing between paragraphs did the trick (as suggested by @Andres as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ul with nav class and li with pull-right

http://jsfiddle.net/N6vGZ/28/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Seb. I actually wanted the two notices to be on separate lines. The link in Andres solution is the way I wanted it. Thanks!